# Backup a keyspace in scylladb

Tags: apache, cassandra, database-backups, database-restore, scylla

I am trying to take a backup of my data in `scylladb`. Currently, my Scylla is in docker.

So I am running this command:

`docker exec -it saif-scylla nodetool snapshot testkeyspace`

`Requested creating snapshot(s) for [testkeyspace] with snapshot name [1564405495089]
Snapshot directory: 1564405495089`

But I can't find any backup in `/var/lib/scylla/data` folder.

Also what exactly it means by "requested".

Also when I list the snapshots by running the command:

`docker exec -it saif-scylla nodetool listsnapshots`

What I can see is:

```
Snapshot name       Keyspace name                Column family name           True size          Size on disk
1564405495089       testkeyspace                 new_events                   0 bytes            0 bytes
1564405495089       testkeyspace                 new_pings                    0 bytes            0 bytes
1564405495089       testkeyspace                 test_pings                   0 bytes            0 bytes
```

I am not getting what's wrong is happening here.

Any Idea, what I am doing wrong?

Any help will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The snapshot files are located in the table directory, under "snapshots".
For example, for keyspace mykeyspace, and table heartrate_ttl, after running `nodetool snapshot mykeyspace;`

```
ls -l /var/lib/scylla/data/mykeyspace/heartrate_ttl-75359ce0b22611e9b18b000000000000/snapshots/1564421433190/
total 44
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root   66 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-CompressionInfo.db
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root  189 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root   10 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-Digest.sha1
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root   16 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-Filter.db
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root   30 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-Index.db
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root   54 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-Scylla.db
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root 4466 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-Statistics.db
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root   92 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-Summary.db
-rw-r--r--. 2 root root  101 Jul 29 17:30 la-4-big-TOC.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root   38 Jul 29 17:30 manifest.json
```

nodetool listsnapshots should give you the snapshot size

```
nodetool listsnapshots
Snapshot Details: 
Snapshot name Keyspace name Column family name True size Size on disk
1564421433190 mykeyspace    heartrate_ttl      0 bytes   4.91 KB
```

I used Scylla 3.0.5 Docker for the above example.

Could it be that you have no data in these tables?

Comment: ```cqlsh> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM testkeyspace.new_pings ;

 count
-------
 39598```

These are the number of records present in one table of that keyspace

Comment: What version Scylla are you using? This might be a bug https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues

Comment: I am currently using the version `2.1.5-0.20180619.72494bbe0` as per the command `docker exec -it saif-scylla scylla --version`.

Should I update it ?

Comment: Yes. Likely you are hitting a fixed issue, maybe https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/3572

Comment: FIles which are stored in `/var/lib/scylla/data/` are large `.db` files. My machine fails during compaction due to space issues. Those `db` files are very large , in `70-80 gb`. Can we move them somewhere else for so that compaction is successful, OR how to get rid of them?